# F# SQL Type Provider Identity Insert

Tags: sql, f#, type-providers

I'm currently using an F# sql type provider to migrate some data between one database to another.

I need to be able to insert identity information (numeric ID column).

The schema for the table has the `Id` column as being identity.

I've run a script to set `identity_insert` to `ON` so that should all be fine.

The issue is that the type-provider-generated insert doesn't actually bother writing the ID value as part of the statement.

Is there a way of forcing it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to meet a deadline.  It's nowhere near ideal but does insert the record with the 'correct' identity.

```
mySequence |> Seq.iter (fun x -> 
  db.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(
    "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].mytable ON 
     insert into mytable (id, name) values({0}, {1}) 
     SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].mytable OFF", x.ID, x.Name) |> ignore)
```

**Edit**

Turns out `DataContext.ExecuteCommand()` will fail if one of the parameters is `null` because it can't infer the type and assumes `Object`

I ended up switching to [Seekwell](https://github.com/reidev275/Seekwell) (nuget package I wrote) which actually looks a bit cleaner too, given you don't have to deal with parameter ordering.

```
let command = new Seekwell.Command(destination)
mySequence |> Seq.iter (fun x -> 
  command.ExecuteScalar(
    "SET IDENTITY_INSERT mydb.dbo.mytable ON 
     insert into mydb.dbo.mytable (id, name) values(@ID, @Name) 
     SET IDENTITY_INSERT mydb.dbo.mytable OFF", x) |> ignore)
```

Comment: Haha yeah, that's pretty much identical to what I ended up doing, except I ended up building the string up by using quotations to declare which properties & columns I wanted to make it in as part of the insert.

Comment: yep,  turns out there's an issue if a property is null.  I've switched to using Seekwell.  Updating with an edit so that hopefully someone else doesn't run into the same thing.

Comment: I had something, that took the identity insert block, and folded a collection of PropertyInfo quotations into the "names" and "values" sections and dealt with things like dropping null value properties etc.

Was a major trial and error job haha.

Basically: https://gist.github.com/ClintPearson-KPMG/f245277d0f31d5b4c58c

Part of a larger "generic-ish" app that does migration, and allowed skipping based on other items that have been skipped etc.